# why fragments are not displaying in tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/profile_image" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/display_username"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"/>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:background="#2F84C8"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#f66"
            app:tabTextColor="#fff"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*in the xml code*

```
TabLayout tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
ViewPager viewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment(),"Chats");
viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UserFragment(),"Users");

viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private ArrayList<Fragment>fragments;
    private  ArrayList<String> titles;

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments=new ArrayList<>();
        this.titles=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public  void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String title){
        fragments.add(fragment);
        titles.add(title);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

*in The Java code*
[hare is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M7HU.jpg)

it displays only the tabs and the tabs name but didn't displat the tabs.
It displaying the titles but not showing fragments.
It displays the titles in tabs they are chats, users, but not showing the fragments. I also have a Toolbar and a actionbar.  please help me.

Comment: Show us your implementation. No one will be able to help you if you don't give insights on your current approach.

Comment: please help now i have uploaded the code

Comment: Your code is fine, seems like a Layout issue. Share the whole layout here.

Comment: now i nhave uploaded the full xml file

Answer (score 0):

Possibility 1: because you use `RelativeLayout` without some `layout_below` tag, the content could be under `AppBar`

Possibility 2: `ViewPager` doesn't need `android:fillViewport="true"` and `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Possibility 3: remove `android:orientation="horizontal"` from `RelativeLayout`. Is not necessary. Try to change to `ConstraintLayout`

OR: provide code from your fragment initialisation. Perhaps content is not setted.

Comment: I have chenge all the points u mention but nothing happened

Comment: @Somnath then please provide `onCreateView` method  and xml of Chat or User Fragment

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
>     private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
> ```

This is an anti-pattern and you should not be doing it.

```
    TabLayout tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    ViewPager viewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

and

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
         super(fm);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         if(position == 0) { return new ChatsFragment(); }
         if(position == 1) { return new UserFragment(); }
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected position: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
         if(position == 0) { return "Chats"; }
         if(position == 1) { return "Users"; }
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected position: " + position);
    }
}
```

If this TabLayout is in a Fragment, then you should be passing `getChildFragmentManager()` to the ViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: No it is in a activity, which pattern should i follow

Comment: Then make your root be `LinearLayout` and `vertical`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all this was resolved when i use
Android: layout_marginTop:"170dp"
In the frame layout
It was resolved.